# Running a separate program alongside web application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have a web application written in Java, deployed through Tomcat. I have a separate Java program that I would like to always have running while the webapp is 'live'. I would only like one instance of this program running at any given time.

What is the best way to go about achieving this effect? Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: Without more details, convert the program in a thread and launch it at tomcat startup. It would be good knowing the relationship between both.

Comment: The webapp lets a user view database contents, the standalone program schedules tasks to populate the database. I think I got the answer I needed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Initialize your standalone application when the context is initialized and destroy it when the web application is destroyed. [An example](http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/).